# Unpack char array to strings in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

There must be a more elegant way to unpack a char array to array of strings:

```
   void loadNames(int size, char *inp[])
   {
      size_t i;
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
          string s = ""
          while ( char(*inp[i]) != '\0' ) s.push_back(*inp[i]++);    
          cout << "String " << i << " = " << s.c_str() << endl;
      }
   }
```

Any clues - highly appreciated!

Comment: you can construct a string from `char*` easily

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how would you do it in the above context?

Comment: Why do you put the C-string into `std::string` at all? You can output it directly.

Comment: @Deduplicator - thanks, my next few lines would actually assign s to a vector<string>. I just wanted to know if there is a more elegant way to unpack *inp[i] to a string, instead of using 'while' loops and push_back()

Comment: Sure there is, maybe add that you want to put them directly into a `std::vector` into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly construct from the `char*`.

```
string s(inp[i]);
cout << "String " << i << " = " << s.c_str() << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple way to construct all those `std::string`s and put them into a `std::vector` (No extraneous copies):

```
std::vector<std::string> v(inp, inp+size);
```

This is the range-initializer of vector, combined with the c-string initializer of string.

Comment: Wow - that's fantastic. Great community here! Thanks!

Comment: if I may ask - how would you do it in reverse? From a vector - load it back to a `**inp` ( `*[]inp` )

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to achieve, but the basis is `std::transform`.

Comment: I use the `**inp` to get data in and out of a DLL. DLL interface does not support vectors. However I prefer working with vectors whilst inside the DLL. The above code is inside the DLL. I wish to read the data in, then modify it and then load it back to `**inp` so I can export it outside of the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` and use its range constructor to fill it. Then just iterate through and print each string:

```c++
void loadNames(int size, char* inp[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(inp, inp + size);
    size = 0;

    for (auto&& x : v) {
        std::cout << "String " << ++size << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```